# PhoneGap GET Ajax request returns commented content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

> index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Blank App</title>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/app.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    datatype:"text",
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#main_div").html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

        <p id="main_div"> Hello World </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

> app.php

```
<?php
    header(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');  
    echo "ok";
 ?>
```

> config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
        A blank PhoneGap app.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
</widget>
```

> returning request in the developer console

```
<!--?php
    header(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');  
    echo "ok";
 ?-->
```

ajax returns commented request
and when i change ajax type to POST it gives error : POST http://ip:3000/ajax/app.php 404 (Not Found)
**Help please !**

Comment: Are you running a PHP interpreter on your phone? I'm guessing not. `<?` and `?>` are treated as HTML comments, unless they are taken out and replaced with content by a PHP interpreter used by a web server running on your phone. Why not simply have a file that says `ok`? Do you really need to run PHP on your phone? **Or** is app.php not a local file on your phone at all? If that's the case, is `index.html` a local file? If not, how are you using PhoneGap if all your resources are remote...?

Comment: actually i am running it on my computer browser and through PhoneGap windows application .. i think PhoneGap application should run it like a server like wamp or not ? and it is just here 'ok' for example but i need it to run PHP  @apsillers

Comment: PhoneGap is **not** a server; it does not parse PHP in any way shape or form. If you need to call out to PHP, you'll have to have those scripts on a backend server capable of running PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 possible causes to your problem.

1.) If you have your PHP files inside of your phonegap www folder this is wrong. You need to host your PHP files on a server. You can either pay for one and put your PHP files on there or you can alternatively download a program like [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) run a php server on your computer and connect to the server via your wifi connection from your phone. The url for ajax would then look like http://192.168.0.4/ajax/file.php. The 192.168.0.4 is the ip address of the computer running the Xampp server you can get this ip by opening command prompt and running ipconfig /all on the computer that is hosting the xampp server and use the local iP4 address.

2.) You are hosting on a server however you haven't entered the full IP.

ajax/app.php => Wrong

http://ipaddress/ajax/file.php => Right

J